# Calling same parameter in a method, needing different results

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, constructor

When I run the method, the result 1 and 2 are the same, I need the results to be different data sets as I pass through different data sets.

Here is what I have at the moment.

```java
public class Stat {

    private double[] data;
    
    public Stat() {
        
        double[] stat = new double[1]; 
        stat[0] = 0.0;
    }
    
    public Stat(double[] d) {
        double[] newData = new double[d.length];
        newData=d;
        data=newData;
        }

    public String toString() {
        String toString="[";
         for(int i=0; i<data.length-1; i++) {
             toString = toString + data[i] + ", ";
             
          }
        return toString;

    }
}
```

And the main method code is:

```java
public class StatTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] data = {10.0, 20.0, 30.0};
        Stat stat1 = new Stat(data);
        data[0] = 100.0;
        data[1] = 200.0;
        data[2] = 300.0;
        Stat stat2 = new Stat(data);
        System.out.println("stat1 data = " + stat1.toString());
        System.out.println("stat2 data = " + stat2.toString());
        System.out.println("The two arrays should be different");
```

Results in two same data sets [100.0, 200.0, 300.0] when stat1 and stat are printed.

I need stat 1 to be 10.0, 20.0, 30.0 and stat 2 to be 100.0, 200.0, 300.0

I have tried to change the orders of

```
newData=d;
data=newData;
```

to

```
data=newData;
newData=d;
```

But this gave me the same results. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Use differents arrays, you overwrite values in `data` which is used by both stat1 and stat2, there is ONE array only so both use the same so both have same result

Comment: Read about how to use arrays. You are using them wrong. The problem is to be found at your method `public Stat(double[] d) {...}`

Comment: I do not understand. would not double[] d create a parameter for a double array to pass through? What is it that you found wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're only assigning a reference to the array passed in the parameter to `Stat` constructor, so both the `data` instance variable inside `Stat` and `data` local variable in the `main` point to the same array, and updating the array in the `main` method updates the array referred to by the `data` in `Stat` class.

```
public Stat(double[] d) {
    double[] newData = new double[d.length];
    newData=d; // here
    data=newData; //here
}
```

Thus, you need to copy the passed array so that changing the array passed as the parameter doesn't update the array referred to in the `Stat` class, like this:

```
public Stat(double[] d) {
    data = Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor saves the reference of the array passed to it, so when that array is changed, so is the data of the instance. Instead, you should create a new array and copy the values of the parameter to it. E.g.:

```
public Stat(double[] d) {
    data = Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length);
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you aren't allowed to use JDK helper methods, you can implement this yourself.

E.g:

```
public Stat(double[] d) {
    data = new int[d.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
        data[i] = d[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me I am a complete newbie here. I am restricted to not use Array method. So I tried data=d; and newData=data; and it does not seem to work.
How should I copy the values of the parameter without using Array method?

Comment: @IanSeol you can copy the array yourself - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `newData=d;` just assign a new variable toe the same array, you need to **copy** the array. Also the condition in your `toString` should be `i < data.length`, but it's easier with a for-each loop

```java
class Stat {
    private double[] data;

    public Stat(double[] d) {
        data = Arrays.copyOf(d, d.length);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder toString = new StringBuilder("[");
        for (double datum : data) {
            toString.append(datum).append(", ");
        }
        return toString.append("]").toString();
    }
}
```